# How to apply Bootstrap 3's form-control class to Google Visualization controlWrapper input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

How to apply Bootstrap 3's form-control class to Google Visualization controlWrapper input?

```
var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                          'controlType': 'StringFilter',
                          'containerId': 'myContainer',
                          'options': {
                            'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
                            "ui": {"label": ""}
                          }
                        });
```

I try to use LESS like below methods,but no one works

**Method :1**

```
<style type="text/less">
        #myContainer .google-visualization-controls-stringfilter {
            input{
                .form-control;
            }
        }
</style>
```

**Method :2**

```
<style type="text/less">
        #myContainer .google-visualization-controls-stringfilter input{
             .form-control;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Any answer for this Question?

Comment: Any answer for this query?